# Verification of ComplexPlot

Tags: plotting, complex

[image]
from Wegert Visual complex functions.

I am trying to verify a phase portrait by reproducing it with Mathematica. The only problem is that I am misunderstanding the `ComplexPlot` syntax.  The complex function associated is: $f(z)=z^5-z^4-z+1$.$\text{this is shown in figure 3.5}$
The pictures on page 67, figure 3.6 says zooming out at infinity of the phase portrait of the polynomial $f$. To do this can someone confirm you do $f\left(1\over z\right) $ and the portrait of at zero? The author claims the two yellow lines emanating from infinity meet at 1. I thought it looks like -1(arrowed) in the picture someone please explain.

Comment: Looks like a picture from [_Visual complex functions_](http://www.visual.wegert.com/) of E. Wegert. If this is really the case, you may want to add a reference to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you're trying to create a "domain coloring" plot for your function, with some aspect of the plot representing the "phase", by which I presume you mean "argument". But there are literally infinitely many such plots, depending on what color scheme you use to represent different values of the argument — and not just the hue, but the intensity/shading.

Mathematica has no such built-in function as `ComplexPhasePlot`. The appropriate one to try is `ComplexPlot`. The documentation explains the syntax.

Note that the correct syntax for you function would be:

```
f[z_]:=z^5-z^4-z+1
```

So start with:

```
ComplexPlot[z^5 - z^4 - z + 1, {z, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then use such options as you want to achieve your goal.

Comment: yes, I believe it is from Wegert's book, mentioned above. In the book phase is defined on p. 13 as: "substitute the argument ϕ by the phase cos ϕ + i sin ϕ whenever possible. Since the phase of z is just  z/|z|, it is well defined for all complex numbers except zero." In the epilog he gives 10 lines of MATLAB code to draw phase portraits.

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DomainColoringForCommonFunctionsInComplexAnalysis/ should be be helpful.

Comment: Note that it may be useful to create a 3D version of such "domain coloring," which perhaps should be called "range coloring." Namely, `ComplexPlot3D[z^5 - z^4 - z + 1, {z, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}]`. That function was new in Mathematica 12 and was updated in 12.1 and 13.0.

Comment: In case of an older version of Mathematica, one can use `ComplexFnPlot`, essentially the same 3D function, which is defined in terms of `Plot3D` in the new book "The Calculus of Complex Functions," by William Johnston.